# Convert a DATEDIFF result to a string, to concatenate another string to it

Tags: sql-server, datediff

I have a DATEDIFF result (in minutes) that i have divided by 1440 to count as days, I wish to add 'Hours' to the end of it but cant figure out how to turn the result into a string first.

```
DATEDIFF(mi,z.entryDate, GETDATE()) / 1440
```

this returns 11, but i want it to read 11 Hours.

Ive tried to CAST AS VARCHAR but think my syntax is wrong. Please Help :)

Comment: did u try - `cast((DATEDIFF(mi,z.entryDate, GETDATE()) / 1440) + ' Hours' as nvarchar)`?

Comment: Yes it still says 'Conversion failed when converting the varchar value ' Hours' to data type int.'

Comment: That wouldn't even be hours, it would be days.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For days:

```
CONVERT(varchar(11), DATEDIFF(minute, z.entryDate, GETDATE()) / 1440) + ' Days'
```

For hours:

```
CONVERT(varchar(11), DATEDIFF(minute, z.entryDate, GETDATE()) / 60) + ' Hours'
```

Comment: Added length to varchar conversion as @aaron-bertrand said

Answer (score 1):

To get hours (rounded, of course), you would divide by 60, not 1440:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), (DATEDIFF(MINUTE, z.entryDate, GETDATE()) / 60)) 
  + ' hours.' FROM ...;
```

If you want to divide by 1440, then the result is in days, not hours:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), (DATEDIFF(MINUTE, z.entryDate, GETDATE()) / 1440)) 
  + ' days.' FROM ...;
```

And please stop using things like `mi` shorthand ([blog post for background](https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations)) and converting to `varchar` without length ([blog post for background](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length)).

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry about my previous post.
this should work :-
    `cast((DATEDIFF(mi,z.entryDate, GETDATE()) / 1440) as nvarchar) + ' Hours'`

Comment: Uh, why **n**varchar? And [why cast without length](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length.aspx)?

Comment: umm, okay I am a naive here. what will happen if I have a million records?

Comment: Sorry, no idea at all what you're asking.